# where should constant variable be redefined in Spree RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

where should constant variable be redefined ?

In my case, Spree::Order::PAYMENT_STATES will be changed

before:

`Spree::Order::PAYMENT_STATES = %w(balance_due checkout completed credit_owed failed paid pending processing void).freeze`

after (post_pay added)

`Spree::Order::PAYMENT_STATES = %w(balance_due checkout completed credit_owed failed paid pending processing void post_pay).freeze`

so in which file should "Spree::Order::PAYMENT_STATES" be redefined in the best way?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a same issue you can try this:

```
Spree::Order.class_eval do
  remove_const(:SHIPMENT_STATES)
  const_set(:SHIPMENT_STATES, %w(backorder canceled partial pending ready shipped delivered))
end
```

Answer (score -2):

In your Spree app, create a file: `app/models/spree/order_decorator.rb` with the following code in it:

```
Spree::Order.class_eval do
  PAYMENT_STATES = %w(balance_due checkout completed credit_owed failed paid pending processing void post_pay).freeze
end
```

This will override the existing Spree::Order::PAYMENT_STATES variable with yours. That should be it!